# Generic in subscript for swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-subscript

I understand that with Swift you can specify a function-specific generic with this form:

```
func someFunction<T>(type: T.Type) {...}
```

However, is it possible to do something similar with subscripts? Where you can specify a type within the brackets like so:

```
subscript<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {...}
```

EDIT: Updated solution based upon the accepted answer

```
subscript(type: AnyClass.Type) -> Any {
    return sizeof(type)
}
```

EDIT 2: Upon testing, It seems that I cannot actually use this subscript. I get "CLASS is not identical to AnyClass.Type" so I am back to square one

Comment: Dang but wouldn't this be awesome. This is frustrating that it isn't supported. A subscript is really just a special function so there's no architectural reason why the compiler couldn't support this. Maybe we'll get it in a future version of the language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't define a `subscript` as a generic function, but you can use a generic type if it's declared at the class level.

For instance, lets say you want to make a class where the `subscript` takes a type `T` and returns a type `U`. That would look something like:

```
class SomeClass<T, U> {
    subscript(someParameter: T) -> U {
        /* something that returns U */
    }
}
```

For example, you could create a `Converter` class that used the `subscript` function to convert from type `T` to type `U`:

***Note:** This is a very contrived example, I wouldn't normally do this this way.*

```
class Converter<T, U> {
    var _converter: (T -> U)

    init(converter: (T -> U)) {
        _converter = converter
    }

    subscript(input: T) -> U {
        let output = _converter(input)
        return output
    }
}

var convert = Converter(converter: {
    (input: Int) -> String in
    return "The number is: \(input)"
})

let s = convert[1]
println(s) // The number is: 1
```

Comment: In my scenario, I am unable to use a class-wide generic. But I am uprooting your answer since it has good information for others

Comment: okay cool this makes sense. But now a question from me: How can you change the generic type if you want to use another in the subscript?

Comment: @returntrue you'd need to have different instances of the class to use different generic types.  `SomeClass<String, Int>` or `SomeClass<Double, UInt8>`, etc.

Comment: @AlexZielenski What is the exact scenario you're in? Are you trying to create an extension for an existing class maybe?

Comment: @AlexZielenski isn't that exactly not the purpose of generics?

Comment: I'm creating an extension for a class. @returntrue It has been possible to create method-specific generics in Swift so since `subscript` is a method I figured I should be able to

Comment: @AlexZielenski Ok, I'm pretty sure you're out of options for generic types on `subscript` then. Can you explain why you want to use a generic type on `subscript`? Maybe there's a different way to solve your specific issue.

Answer (score 7):

Generic subscripts are now available in [Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md): [SE-0148](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0148-generic-subscripts.md)

Answer (score 2):

Generic Subscript is supported from Swift 4.0

```
struct GenericDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value> {
  private var data: [Key: Value]

  init(data: [Key: Value]) {
    self.data = data
  }

  subscript<T>(key: Key) -> T? {
    return data[key] as? T
  }
}

// Dictionary of type: [String: Any]
var earthData = GenericDictionary(data: ["name": "Earth", "population": 7500000000, "moons": 1])

// Automatically infers return type without "as? String"
let name: String? = earthData["name"]

// Automatically infers return type without "as? Int"
let population: Int? = earthData["population"]
```

For [reference](https://www.raywenderlich.com/582-what-s-new-in-swift-4)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Instead you could use Any or AnyObject, and cast the result of the function back to your specified type.

```
subscript(type: AnyObject) -> AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

Tip: Instead of `type: T.Type`, use `type: T`.

Comment: I tried `type:T` but I always get the error "Expected member name or constructor call after type name"

Comment: ah then T isn't a class?

Comment: T is a class like UInt8. I have to input UInt8.self to get this to build. Also, how may I be able to use an input the input `type` into something such as `sizeof()`

Comment: That's not what I meant but I will update my answer with my solution based upon what you gave me